# Find the path of browser default downloads folder

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-7

how can we find the path of browser default downloads folder in c# / asp.net?

For example I can get the path of user desktop like :

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

You can't find that out in a web application. It's up to the user to decide which browser to use and how to configure it and where to save downloaded files by default and you have absolutely no way of interfering or even knowing his choices from a web application.

Answer (score 0):

First of all looking at MSDN on `Environment.SpecialFolder` there is no download folder, and the reason is that this is different for every browser.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx

And there have nothing to do with asp.net, if you look it from the server side you just get a directory on nowhere, meaning that this have nothing to do with the web application that run under the pool.

### What you can do

You can use the [HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainapppath(v=vs.110).aspx) and use it to know where your site lives, and there place a "download" directory and use this full path:

```
HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "download/"
```

for download/upload files.

Comment: I try to find a place in client computer to download my files without needind any permission. Where should I create my new folder and download my files in it ?

Comment: @user741319 ok, you try that on client, but if you use asp.net the program run on server. This is not possible to find from yours server program, your client default directory. And also is different for every browser.

Comment: @user741319 Browsers don't allow that. It would be a security issue.

Comment: How can I over this security problem?

Comment: @user741319 From the server side forget it - why is this so special ? what you try to archive here ?

Comment: it isn't speacial. Actually this folder will be very common.In this folder there will be files which client dowloads himself. but I couldn't over this problem with classic asp methods. Because I need to give to the program any path of client computer

Comment: @user741319 Tell me this is a web application or a desktop application ?

Comment: web application. But my files which client may want to download aren't stored in server. They are in sftp. My website is only user interface between sftp and client. So I can't do this work with giving a path ~/downloads/example.doc unfortunately. Because I don't store any file in downloads folder in server all of them in other server (sftp)