# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API : how to download file to folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project.

I use download file code:

```
[HttpGet("download3")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFile(string bucketName, string fileName)
{
    var amUp = new AmazonUploader();

    using (var amazonS3client = amUp.GetS3Client())
    {
        var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(amazonS3client);

        var response = await transferUtility.S3Client.GetObjectAsync(new GetObjectRequest()
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,

            Key = fileName
        });

        if (response.ResponseStream == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return File(response.ResponseStream, response.Headers.ContentType, fileName);
    }
}
```

I see the OK answer in Swagger and response contains link "download file", then `DialogSaveAs` appears etc.

The question is: how to download and save file to `filePath` passed as parameter?

Comment: You can't set a download location for files from the server side. There are security implications (say a malicious website decides to download "explorer.exe" to "C:\Windows").

Comment: What if a client app passed path (local clients path) as a controller method parameter? For example: the client app needs a file for next printing etc. It downloads file to predefined TEMP folder and do not provide dialog Save as. Cant it be?

Comment: @ZedZip As you were already told, you need to do it *client* side.  This is separated from the server for a reason

Comment: @ZedZip what you ask doesn't exist in HTTP itself. The `Content-Disposition` header can only suggest a file name, never a folder. It's entirely up to the browser or client where that file is stored, or with what name. If the server could specify folders, malware would have no problem saving itself to any folder on a user's computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see the OK answer in Swagger and response contains link "download
> file", then DialogSaveAs appears etc.
>
> The question is: how to download and save file to filePath passed as
> parameter?

Well, what **[@Heretic Monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/heretic-monkey)** has commented is correct, we cannot override or cannot set specific download path neither from server or client side. Becuase,from web application we cannot decide that and it has invloved malicious risk facotrs.

It's completely upon the user to decide which browser to use and how to configure it and which specific location they want to save downloaded files.  From application both in server and client side absolutely no way of implementing that.

Therefore, it can be said that, in asp.net core server side we cannot set the path of downloding file and also using any client side scripting language, for instance, Javascript, not be able to get information about the user's filesystem. The default download path might also contain confidencial information, which is threatening, so it never allows to do that.

**Note:** I have tested in many ways, and have gone through couple of articles and [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391322/find-the-path-of-browser-default-downloads-folder) which confirmed that solely. [You can check here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840923/get-browser-download-path-with-javascript)